# How do I embed and read a text file ina WP7 app?

Tags: silverlight, resources, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to include a text file that contains some static data that I need to read in when the app starts up. I've added the file and marked the Build Action to "Resource" but I'm unsure of how to actually read it in as a stream. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Try marking test file as content...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `System.Windows.Application.GetResourceStream` method:

```
var resource = System.Windows.Application.GetResourceStream(
                   new Uri("textfile.txt",UriKind.Relative));
```

should do the trick

Comment: This didn't work for me.  I needed the full pack Uri as shown below.

Comment: @BrentSchooley: you had it set as resource instead of content, didn't you?

Answer (score 24):

try this:

```
var resource = Application.GetResourceStream(
                               new Uri(@"/YOURASSEMBLYNAME;component/Stations.txt", 
                               UriKind.Relative));

StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(resource.Stream);

string x = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

That should work for you.