# How can I access a text file in the project explorer "read, write" which is not in the isolated storage in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, text, explorer

How can I access a text file in the project explorer "read, write" which is not in the isolated storage in Windows Phone 7?
I want it to be in the project explorer for me and i don't want it to be in the isolated storage .. got the point?
thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some resources that useful for you.

Read File

```
 var resource = System.Windows.Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("textfile.txt", UriKind.Relative)
```

Write File

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fileName, true))

{

    writer.Write("Write some text here");

}
```

More information:

[read file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940270/read-file-in-c-sharp-net)

[read text file in windows phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920971/how-do-i-embed-and-read-a-text-file-ina-wp7-app)

[write file](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/how-to-write-to-a-text-file-in-C-Sharp/)