# Editing a xml file located project root on WP8

Tags: xml, windows-phone-8

I want to change a value of an XML file which is located in project root folder.

Following code can read "isFirstUse" and changes the value "YES" to "NO".

I have a XML file named "Values.xml" in project root, however, I can't save changes on file.

```
public void writeFile()
    {
        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("Values.xml");
        lblSafakCount.Text = xDoc.Descendants("isFirstUse").FirstOrDefault().Value.ToString();

        XElement xElm = xDoc.Descendants("isFirstUse").FirstOrDefault();
        xElm.Value = "NO";
        xElm.Save("Values.xml");
    }
```

"xElm.Save("Values.xml")" code not saving, it requires stream or textwriter and denies string.
How can I edit local(project root, not phone storage) XML file?
Thanks.

Comment: How about following [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17246898/2998271), with a little modification : `writer.Write(xDoc.ToString());`

Comment: Hi har07, tried the answer you post but object "writer" requires a stream. I'm unable to write filename as string. Any idea?