# How to store few kbytes of initial data for WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, storage, assets

Just trying to write my first ever WP7 app. I have several hundreds of kbytes of ASCII alike text data (kinda manual or book) which need to be shown in my app.

Just wondering where to store them? Like **assets** for Android or **res** for J2ME?

P.S. Don't tell me anything about SQL! So far I don't need it - just need to find appropriate place to store some text/xml data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the text is to be embedded in the app, you can use a resources (.resx) file  (Add > New Item > Resources File). This is also useful if you plan to localize it at some point.

Alternatively, you could include the text/XML in its own file in the project as an embedded resource and access that. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920971/how-do-i-embed-and-read-a-text-file-ina-wp7-app) contains useful references on how then to access that file.