# Use local file with StringReader

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, stringreader

I'm developing an app for WP.

I'm using a XML file online, it's working fine but when I want to use the same XML file in local storing, this doesn't work...

I added it at my project.

To use it online, I'm using that :

```
client.DownloadStringCompleted += client_DownloadStringCompleted;
client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://exemple.com/news.xml"), "News");
```

And in my function client_DownloadStringCompleted, I read like that:

```
StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(e.Result);
```

So this it's working but with my local file I'm doing like that directly and it's not working :

```
StringReader stringReader = new StringReader("news.xml");
```

Do you know how I can fix that ?

Thank you for your help.

EDIT :
It's ok, thanks for your help !

I wrote that :

```
var resource = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(@"/YOURASSEMBLYNAME;component/news.xml", UriKind.Relative));
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(resource.Stream);
StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
```

And I used the file like a resource.

Comment: How is the file getting into local storage in the first place? Unless you get the user to download it of course.

Comment: The file is in local by default. And I want to use StringReader with this local file.

Comment: See the answer to this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920971/how-do-i-embed-and-read-a-text-file-ina-wp7-app - you need to embed the file as a resource

Comment: Thank ChrisF, I resolved the problem with your help !

Answer (score 3):

The parameter of the StringReader constructor is the string that you want to read.

In the code that you have that does not work, you are reading the name of the file not the contents of the file.