# Textfile Reading, Windows Phone 8 and MonoGame

Tags: c#, file-io, windows-phone-8, monogame

I'm having a problem with reading simple text file containing my level information using Windows Phone 8 and MonoGame framework.

my file reading function works just fine with a normal Windows Phone 8 project but when I try to use it on monogame project it gives me this error when its trying to create new FileStream:

> "An exception of type 'System.MethodAccessException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code"

this is my file reading function

```
private string readFile(string fileName)
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);

    byte[] bytes = new byte[fs.Length];
    int numBytesToRead = (int)fs.Length;
    int numBytesRead = 0;
    while (numBytesToRead > 0)
    {
        int n = fs.Read(bytes, numBytesRead, numBytesToRead);

        if (n == 0)
        {
            break;
        }

        numBytesToRead -= n;
        numBytesRead += n;
    }

    numBytesToRead = bytes.Length;
    return System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

Is my approach complitely wrong or does anyone have ideas why this isnt working? I'm trying to read the file from my project files.

Comment: That's almost certainly not your problem, but you seem to have reimplemented File.ReadAllText here. Also, you forgot to dispose of that stream.

Comment: Also, when the exception is thrown (while debugging), you should be able to click "View Detail..." and see some more specific information about your exception. Maybe try that and post the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Windows Phone apps are sandboxed, you would typically use the Isolated Storage classes for saving files, and not go directly to System.IO. But since you mention level information (compiled into your app?), perhaps the following link will help:

[How do I embed and read a text file ina WP7 app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920971/how-do-i-embed-and-read-a-text-file-ina-wp7-app)