# Windows Phone read from text file

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm writing an app that reads data from a text file and uses that as the basis of the app. This is just a simple text file with several lines of data that the program needs. I've included the text file as part of the project in visual studio. However, when I try to run the app and read the text file using a StreamReader, it throws an error:

"System.MethodAccessException: Attempt by security transparent method 'App.MainPage..ctor()' to access security critical method 'System.IO.File.Exists(System.String)' failed.
   at System.IO.File.Exists(String path)"

This text file is very important to the function of the app. Is there any way I can include it with the XAP when people download it and read it directly from within the app?

Comment: please share some pieces of code

Comment: Are you reading the file like in this [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681698(v=vs.105).aspx)?

Comment: I've been attempting to read it as you would on a regular Windows desktop app using a StreamReader.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I embed and read a text file ina WP7 app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920971/how-do-i-embed-and-read-a-text-file-ina-wp7-app)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the solution to read a text file from solution in wp7 app.

1. Copy text file in your solution.
2. Right Click -> Properties
3. Now set Build Action to Resource.

   ```
   System.IO.Stream src = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("solutionname;component/text file name", UriKind.Relative)).Stream;
               using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(src))
                 {
                    string text = sr.ReadToEnd();
                 }
   ```

Comment: Good job. Nice work. If some wants to assign this to Textblock, so he/she should add this : texBlock1.Text = text;

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`IsolatedStorageFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) class to access your text file within your Windows Phone application. To read it, open a new `FileStream`. You can then create a StreamReader or a StreamWriter with that `FileStream`.

The following code accesses `IsolatedStorageFile` and opens a new StreamReader to read the content.

```
        using (IsolatedStorageFile f = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            //To read
            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(f.OpenFile("settings.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate)))
            {
                string text = r.ReadToEnd();
            }

            //To write
            using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(f.OpenFile("settings.txt", FileMode.Create)))
            {
                w.Write("Hello World");
            }
        }
```