# How to Copy Files from Installed location to Isolated Storage in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8, cocos2d-x

I am developing an app for WP8 using cocos2dx. I am not being able to find a copy function that helps me copy files from Installed location to Isolated Storage. Does anyone know how to do this. Please Help

Comment: I am not familiar with cocos2dx and c++, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20537820/windows-phone-read-from-text-file/20545191#20545191 is a example in c# to get file from installed location

Comment: @Jaihind Thank you but i am looking for a function in c++

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at ["Marble Game"](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Marble-Maze-sample-for-c9f3706b) sample from Microsoft - it contains a lot of illustrative code snippets. For example, this is minor edit of loading data (asynchronously):

```
    concurrency::task<Platform::Array<byte>^> ReadDataAsync(
        _In_ Windows::Storage::StorageFolder^ location,
        _In_ Platform::String^ filename
        )
    {
        return concurrency::task<Windows::Storage::StorageFile^>(location->GetFileAsync(filename)).then([=](Windows::Storage::StorageFile^ file)
        {
            return file->OpenReadAsync();
        }).then([=](Windows::Storage::Streams::IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType^ stream)
        {
            uint32 fileSize = static_cast<uint32>(stream->Size);
            auto reader = ref new Windows::Storage::Streams::DataReader(stream);

            return concurrency::task<uint32>(reader->LoadAsync(fileSize)).then([=](uint32 count)
            {
                auto fileData = ref new Platform::Array<byte>(fileSize);
                reader->ReadBytes(fileData);
                return fileData;
            });
        });
    }
```

How to use (assumption: you have my_data.xml included to your project, and "Content=True")

```
        PCWSTR XML_FILE = L"my_data.xml"; // pay attention this is wide string
        auto folder = Windows::ApplicationModel::Package::Current->InstalledLocation;
        auto file = ref new Platform::String(XML_FILE);

        concurrency::task<Platform::Array<byte>^> data_task = ReadDataAsync(folder, file);
        concurrency::task_status res = data_task.wait();
        Platform::Array<byte>^ data_buf = data_task.get();
```

Now you have a buffer of data, feel free to consume it or save to Isolated storage upon your needs.